# Postman: Is there a way to read browser's localStorage values in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

After logging into the website,  I need to make a POST call in Postman but the URL requires an userID which is stored in the browser's localStorage after login (refer to screenshot). The login API call does not return the userID in the response. Is there a way to fetch this value in Postman?

[image]

Comment: Nope, being the simple answer. :D

Comment: Are there other ways to get it into Postman :D

Comment: Return it in the response 